# Reconciling answers with old mod notices

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

[Search shows](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+hasnotice%3A1) several answers with old mod [notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-notice/info), could these be [reconciled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconciliation_%28accounting%29)?

At first I thought to flag them but there seems to be too many and some are not quite clear cut so I decided to ask at meta instead.

1. Notice appears ignored:

   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194589
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151524
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171241
   - (*) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201190
   - (*) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/155059
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/177532
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/202497
   - (*) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/172957
2. There was an edit but I can't tell if the issue is addressed indeed:

   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/167776
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185954
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/173248
3. Notice appears to be obsoleted by answer edits:

   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175249
   - (*) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148870
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/167393
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/159829
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/228080
   - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/198499

In list above, (*) denotes cases where not only answer but also question itself looks troublesome.

I am particularly concerned about answers in first and last groups. First makes site visitors think that it's okay to ignore mod notice, last makes them think that moderators ignore attempts to improve.

Comment: FWIW I flagged first answer in the list referring moderator to take a look at this meta post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that in my early mod days I liked to give people a chance to improve or expand on their one line answers and sometimes some of them would slip through the cracks.  I stopped doing this because I literally couldn't keep track of the tsunami deluge of low quality answers anymore.  The second reason I stopped doing this for the most part is because optimistically 2% of people cared to actually expand or fix their answers.  Half of those people ended up just plagiarizing something anyway.

I think we should clean these up and by clean up I mean delete the answers that encouraged the mod notice to begin with.  I would say they had fair warning in most cases.

The following answers have had comment cleanup and post notice removal.  Anything else was deleted or converted to comment.

- [Git workflow for small teams](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175034/git-workflow-for-small-teams/175249)
- [Where is it permissible to add logging code in a MVC model?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/where-is-it-permissible-to-add-logging-code-in-a-mvc-model/173248)
- [How can I deal with a team member who dislikes making comments in code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185923/how-can-i-deal-with-a-team-member-who-dislikes-making-comments-in-code/185954)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148861/fastest-way-to-open-a-file-in-visual-studio-knowing-only-its-name/148870
- [Examples of Finite State Machines](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47806/examples-of-finite-state-machines/167393)
- [easiest way for push notifications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158311/easiest-way-for-push-notifications/159829)
- [Is there a compliance test for C++ compilers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199708/is-there-a-compliance-test-for-c-compilers/228080)
- [iOS App Signing and Certificates](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188289/ios-app-signing-and-certificates/198499)

**NOTE:** Please give a second look to this answer.  I am not entirely sure this is even answering the question that was asked.

[Is there a compliance test for C++ compilers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199708/is-there-a-compliance-test-for-c-compilers/228080)

Comment: wrt "compliance test" question, per my reading it's asking for [off-site resource recommendations](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487): _"Is there, somewhere, a freely usable/accessible script, source file, or whatever, that is blah blah"_. My close vote on it has expired over a year ago